# Will the Serilog logging library work in a .net WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serilog

I have a .Net C# WPF application.
I'm trying to add rolling logs to the app.
In Asp.Net applications, we've previously used the package Serilog.

Does Serilog work .Net desktop (non-asp.net) applications?
I googled around and saw there were some issues regarding it, but
it wasn't clear to that they were actually resolved.

**Here is what the initialization of my Serilog Logger looks like:**

```
string logsDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "logs");

// Configure Serilog pipeline
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .MinimumLevel.Debug()
   .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(logsDirectory, "log-{Date}.txt"))
   .CreateLogger();
```

**I get the followint compilation error for "RollingLog()".**

> Error CS1061  'LoggerSinkConfiguration' does not contain a definition
> for 'RollingFile' and no extension method 'RollingFile' accepting a
> first argument of type 'LoggerSinkConfiguration' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can one git it to work with WPF?

Comment: To answer your first question: Serilog is not an ASP.Net specific library, you can absolutely use it with WPF applications.  Your error is due to something beyond that scope

Comment: OK. That's good news. Am I missing a reference? This is what I'm currently using in the file: 
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;

Comment: yeah you are missing a NuGet package - see my answer I just posted

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the Serilog RollingFile NuGetPackage if you would like to use rolling logs:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile
```

For more details on using this package, see [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile)

As I commented on your question - Serilog is not ASP.Net specific, it is a generic C# logging library.